# Control LED strip with voice

Tags: led

I have a Raspberry Pi, an ADC microphone, and an LED strip. I would like to control the LED color by voice, e.g. say "red" and change the lights to red. I imagine it's possible because [Tensorflow can recognize keywords](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio) and Raspberry Pi runs Python and Tensorflow. I would also like to view and alter the source code for LED commands, e.g. making the transition to a new color happen like a wave or with some blinks.

I found [an instructable](https://www.instructables.com/RGB-LED-Strip-Controlled-by-Voice/), which requires Ozeki 10 (an operating system) and an Arduino Nano in addition to what I have and where I may not be able to modify the source code; and a [balena project](https://www.balena.io/blog/control-your-christmas-tree-a-raspberry-pi-powered-rgb-led-matrix-v2/), which does not have voice recognition.

Has anyone developed such a project, ideally on Balena Cloud that I can easily deploy to my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: what is stopping you from developing your project? ... `where can i find code?` is not a question about a problem you are facing

Comment: @jstola This project is for a 13-year old interested in LEDs and programming to implement at home. I can provide some help over the phone but I am not there.